# Java HashMap associative multi dimensional array can not create or add elements

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, hashmap

Okay so I have spent several hours trying to wrap my head around this concept of a HashMap in Java but am just not able to figure it out. I have looked at many tutorials but none seem to address my exact requirement and I cannot get it to work.

I am trying to create an associative multi dimensional array in Java (or something similar) so that I can both save to and retrieve from the array with keys that are Strings.

This is how I would do it in PHP and explains it best what I am trying to do:

```
//loop one - assign the names
myArray['en']['name'] = "english name";
myArray['fr']['name'] = "french name";
myArray['es']['name'] = "spanish name";

//loop two - assign the description
myArray['en']['desc'] = "english description";
myArray['fr']['desc'] = "french description";
myArray['es']['desc'] = "spanish description";

//loop three - assign the keywords
myArray['en']['keys'] = "english keywords";
myArray['fr']['keys'] = "french keywords";
myArray['es']['keys'] = "spanish keywords";

//later on in the code be able to retrive any value similar to this
english_name = myArray['en']['name'];
french_name = myArray['fr']['name'];
spanish_name = myArray['es']['name'];
```

This is what I tried in Java but it is not working:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> myArray = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();

myArray.put("en" , put("name", "english name")); //gives me "cannot find symbol" at second put

myArray.put("en" , ("name", "english name")); //gives me "')' expected" after second comma
```

So I am sure its something simple that I am missing but please point it out because this is very frustrating!

Thanks

**EDIT:**

So here is some working code on how I implemented the answer I accepted:

```
import java.util.*;

HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> finalArray = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();

String[] langArray = {"en","fr","de","no","es"};

//Initialize each language key ahead of time
for(String lang : langArray) { // foreach lang in langArray
  if (!finalArray.containsKey(lang)) {
    finalArray.put(lang, new HashMap<String, String>());
  }
}

//loop one - assign names
for(String lang : langArray) {
  String theName = lang + " name"; //go get the name from somewhere
  finalArray.get(lang).put("name", theName);
}

//loop two - assign description
for(String lang : langArray) {
  String theDesc = lang + " description"; //go get the description from somewhere
  finalArray.get(lang).put("desc", theDesc);
}

//loop three - assign keywords
for(String lang : langArray) {
  String theKeys = lang + " keywords"; //go get the keywords from somewhere
  finalArray.get(lang).put("keys", theKeys);
}

//display output
for(String lang : langArray) {
  System.out.println("LANGUAGE: " + lang);
  System.out.println(finalArray.get(lang).get("name"));
  System.out.println(finalArray.get(lang).get("desc"));
  System.out.println(finalArray.get(lang).get("keys"));
}

//example to retrieve/get values
String english_name = finalArray.get("en").get("name");
String french_desc = finalArray.get("fr").get("desc");
```

Comment: Well after reading some answers I see that it is not so simple! Thanks for responses!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> myArray = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();

if (!myArray.containsKey("en")) {
    myArray.put("en", new HashMap<String, String>());
}
myArray.get("en").put("name", "english name");
```

In Java you have to be explicit about when you are creating an object. In this case first we check if there is already a `HashMap` object stored in our outer `HashMap` under the key "en". If not, we create an empty one.

Now to put a new value into it we have to first get it from the outer `HashMap`, then put the new value.

Comment: Ok this works perfect for my use case scenario. I can then add `name` and `desc` and `keys` to each language key anytime! I have marked this as correct.

Answer (score 4):

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> myArray = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> value = new HashMap<String, String>();
value.put("name", "English name");
value.put("desc", "English description");
value.put("keys", "English keywords");

myArray.put("en" , value);

value = new HashMap<String, String>();
value.put("name", "French name");
value.put("desc", "French description");
value.put("keys", "French keywords");

myArray.put("fr" , value);
```

Comment: `name`, `desc` and `keys` will not be assigned at the same time so this is not working for me. They get assigned in different loops so I end up with no `name` and no `desc` and only `keys` left. I have updated my PHP example above to better illustrate what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there's no concise syntax for constructing populated maps in Java. You'll have to write it out long-hand. A separate helper method can make it a little simpler:

```
HashMap<String, String> makeMap(String name, String desc, String keys) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    // Before Java 7, above must be: new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("name", name);
    map.put("desc", desc);
    map.put("keys", keys);
}
```

Then:

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> myArray = new HashMap<>();
myArray.put("en",
    makeMap("english name", "english description", "english keywords"));
// etc.
```

You would retrieve it with:

```
english_name = myArray.get("en").get("name");
```

Comment: I am not sure this will work as I am not adding them all at the same time. I need to add the name during one loop then the desc in a different loop and the keys again in a third loop. I have updated my PHP example above to better illustrate what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.HashMap;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Creating array
        HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>> myArray = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
        // Setting values
        for(int i=0; i<100;i++) {
            myArray.put("key1"+i, new HashMap<String, String>());
            myArray.get("key1"+i).put("key2"+i, "value"+i);
        }
        // Getting values
        for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        System.out.println(myArray.get("key1"+i).get("key2"+i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide more explanation on your code, so that anyone who reads it will get the idea.

Comment: @Zeina This code is helpful, where you has two keys and one value equivalent to that keys

Comment: Beautiful example.  Except the "getting values" part would be more valuable if you approached it as if you didn't know how many things were in it.

Answer (score 0):

I really liked the example by "dAv dEv", though he didn't really fill his double array of keys (I added a loop within a loop). I also like TreeMaps better than HashMaps because they aren't as random.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>> myArray = 
                    new TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String, String>>();
String[] roles = { "Help Desk", "Administrator", "Super Use", ... };
String[] elements = { "Hydrogen", "Helium", "Lithium", "Beryllium", ... };

// Setting values TODO: read data values from Excel spreadsheet (or wherever)
for(String role : roles) {
        myArray.put(role, new TreeMap<String, String>());
        for (String elementName : elements) {
            String value = Utils.getHumanName("first", true);
            myArray.get(role).put(elementName, value);
        }
}
// Getting values
for (Map.Entry<String,TreeMap<String,String>> entry1 : myArray.entrySet()) {
    String key1 = entry1.getKey();
    TreeMap<String,String> value1 = entry1.getValue();
    for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry2 : value1.entrySet()) {
            String key2 = entry2.getKey();
            String value2 = entry2.getValue();
            System.out.println("(" + key1 + ", " + key2 + ") = " +
                                       myArray.get(key1).get(key2));
    }
}
```

P.S.  I used Utils.getHumanName() as my data generator. You will need to use your own.