# Create a list of key value objects

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, key-value

I am trying to create a list of key-value pairs.  Here is what I have so far:

```
Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>().put(songID, songList.get(i).name);
```

This gives me the following error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Map

Also, how would I iterate through these?  Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When you call `put` on the map of type `Map <Integer,String>`, you will get the String returned. So when you do this:

```
new HashMap<Integer,String>().put(songID, songList.get(i).name);
```

it will return a `String`

and when you try to assign it to a map

```
Map<Integer,String> map
```

compiler throws an error,

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Map

Here is the signature of put method form [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29):

```
public V put(K key,
             V value)
```

you need to break down the this complex problematic statement:

```
Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>().put(songID, songList.get(i).name);
```

to something like:

```
Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

map.put(songID, songList.get(i).name);
```

Comment: thank you for breaking the problem down and explaining it step by step.  i was confused with the two steps initially when I saw it on another question.

Comment: You can also exploit anonymous inner classes when you need to. But I hear that not everyone is comfortable with them.

Answer (score 0):

The answer on this thread:
[Java HashMap associative multi dimensional array can not create or add elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326386/java-hashmap-associative-multi-dimensional-array-can-not-create-or-add-elements/18326441#18326441)

has an example of how to do this.

Comment: Frankly, I'm not sure how your answer pertains to the question. (I never down voted btw)

Comment: It pertains to the question because it contains an example of how to solve this problem. The example shows how to create a HashMap and put multiple key-value pairs into it.

Comment: I didn't vote down on this either (just upvoted) but that page had a lot of information, thank you!  I saw a lot of similar pages but missed that one.  Will edit my initial post with answer.