# Is it possible this php script to jsp script?

Tags: java, php, json, jsonp, jackson

I want to convert this php to jsp script.. since i don't know php , i cant do it.. Please guide me..

The PHP creates a JSON object from associative array... But java have no associatve arrays , i have trouble from converting it.

```
$response->page = $page;
$response->total = $total_pages;
$response->records = $count;
$i=0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
/*
    $response->rows[$i]['id']=$row[id];
    $response->rows[$i]['cell']=array($row[id],$row[invdate],$row[name],$row[amount],$row[tax],$row[total],$row[note]);
*/
    $response->rows[$i]['id']=$row['id'];
    $response->rows[$i]['name']=$row['name'];
    $response->rows[$i]['author']=$row['author'];
    //$response->rows[$i]=array($row[id],$row[invdate],$row[name],$row[amount],$row[tax],$row[total],$row[note]);
    $i++;
    echo json_encode($response);
```

The above code is in PHP. I have to convert to PHP.. This is the tried code..

***My  Code***

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class MapToJSONExample {


ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();


try {
int i=0;
.....
.....
.....

Map<String, Object> mapObject = new HashMap<String, Object>();
// page,total,records are string var.

mapObject.put("page", page);
mapObject.put("total", total);
mapObject.put("records", records);
List<Object> myList[count]  = new ArrayList<Object>();

while (rs.next())
{

myList[i].add(rs.getString("id");
myList[i].add("name");
myList[i].add("author"); 

mapObject.put("rows", myList[i]);  

} 



objectMapper.writeValue(out);

} catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
```

Is it  right ? Pls help me

Comment: @Bryan Do above code work ?

Comment: Nevermind you are using a map, what's the problem?

Comment: @Bryan $response->rows[$i]['id']=$row['id'];
    $response->rows[$i]['name']=$row['name'];
    $response->rows[$i]['author']=$row['author']; .. How to convert this to jsp

Comment: where are you getting the $rows from in java? It's coming from a DB query in the php.

Comment: @Bryan .. I want to convert associative array of php to java with similar form

Comment: in the second half use a map instead of a list. Like you did above. This looks pretty similar and might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326386/java-hashmap-associative-multi-dimensional-array-can-not-create-or-add-elements

Comment: If you don't know PHP but JSP then forget about the PHP implementation details. Take the high level requirements / use cases and implement it the JSP/Java way.